# How to count number of a changes on string with javascript

Tags: javascript, levenshtein-distance

I am trying to count number of a changes on one field ( one string ) with javascript. For example on name= MARTIN :  MARTI => 1 change MARTINE => 1 change MATRIN => 2 changes MARBOM => 3 changes

Comment: Why is "marbon" 3 changes? Only "b" and "o" have changed.

Comment: N is not a change it was here before

Comment: Considering the example name : he is 'MARBOM' not 'MARBON' so the changes are 3 :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called the levenshtein distance, use that: http://www.dzone.com/snippets/javascript-implementation